# I manage to connect to Azure Analysis Services from SSMS, but not from SSIS

Tags: ssms, ssis, azure-analysis-services

I'm new to the Microsoft Server Suite.

I've downloaded SSMS and connected to Azure Analysis Services from it. I'm able to query my data using mdx without any problems.

However, I actually intend to build an ETL pipeline with the AAS cube as one of the sources. So I installed SSIS and have been trying to connect it to the AAS cube.

I first add "Analysis Services Processing Task" to the package. The result looks ok (when I click on "Test connection" the result is positive). But when I click on "Add", it doesn't detect any cubes (there are two on the AAS server specified):

[image]

I assumed it worked anyway, but I can't query the cube no matter how I try to do that. I added "Execute SQL task", but when I run it, it gives me an error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The error message is:

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ".
Error: 0xC00291EC at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Failed to acquire connection "asazure://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/xxxx". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
Task failed: Execute SQL Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\49176\source\repos\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[18664] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Any ideas?